# (Haskell) Trying to derive Show class on data. Program gives warning on the compile time, then invades all the RAM at runtime. What is the reason?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, polymorphism, ghci

While trying to derive show on user-defined data in Haskell, getting an out-of-memory error. What is the reason?

```
--ghc 8.0.2

class X a where
    f::a->a
    f a = a
    
data T = AA | BB
instance X T
instance Show T

var::T
var = AA

main = print $ var
```

I expected from Haskell that making T instacne of class X and class Show, and printing AA as a result. The instance function works on class X  (instance X T) however not on class Show (instance X Show).

The expected behaviour is the behaviour of below code:

```
--ghc 8.0.2

class X a where
    f::a->a
    f a = a
    
data T = AA | BB deriving Show --notice I changed here
instance X T
--notice I changed here

var::T
var = AA

main = print $ var
```

-------------------------Edited------------------------

The compilation output is :

```
$ ghc test.hs -o test

[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, test.o )

test.hs:8:10: warning: [-Wmissing-methods]
    • No explicit implementation for
        either ‘showsPrec’ or ‘show’
    • In the instance declaration for ‘Show T’
  |
8 | instance Show T
  |          ^^^^^^
Linking test ...
```

No output in the runtime:

```
$./test
```

When the compiled program is running, it invades all of the available RAM of my computer. When I try to run it with interactive GHCi, it throws a stack overflow error.

Why executable trys to allocate infinite memory while trying to instantiate T as in the first code sample? Is it a bug or something else related to the functional programming paradigm? Or some restriction related to the type polymorphism?

-------------------------Edited------------------------

-------------------------OLD------------------------

And the script output is :
[code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gsaqo.png)

```
GHCi, version 8.6.5: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( outofmemory.hs, interpreted )

outofmemory.hs:9:10: warning: [-Wmissing-methods]
    • No explicit implementation for
        either ‘showsPrec’ or ‘show’
    • In the instance declaration for ‘Show T’
  |
9 | instance Show T
  |          ^^^^^^
Ok, one module loaded.
```

Why ghci trys to allocate infinite memory while trying to instantiate T as in the first code sample? Is it a bug or something else related to the functional programming paradigm? Or some restriction related to the type polymorphism?

-------------------------OLD------------------------

Comment: The output part was not clear in the question, I have edited more clear explanation of the compilation results. Thank you @jf_ for the feedback about the filename.

Answer (score 2):

The error output does not say that there is anything out of memory, but I think your source file is just called `outofmemory`.

Regarding your error: The typeclass `T` does not have any functions for which an instantiation would have to supply implementations, but `Show` does. You need to implement the function `show` to make your type an instance of `Show`, for example like this:

```
instance Show T where
    show AA = "AA"
    show BB = "BB"
```

You would trigger the same error with `X` if you would leave out the default implementation of `f` like this:

```
class X a where
    f::a->a
--    f a = a -- no default
```

The `deriving` keyword allows for deriving automatic instantiations of the type classes `Read`, `Show`, `Bounded`, `Enum`, `Eq`, and `Ord`. This is provided by the compiler. You cannot use that with your own type.

Answer (score 2):

When you define an instance, you should always define the related class methods. When you don't, class defaults are used to fill the required definitions.

It turns out that, in many classes, the defaults define the methods using mutual recursion. E.g. we might have the following defaults:

```
class Eq a where
   (==) :: a -> a -> Bool
   x == y = not (x /= y)
   (/=) :: a -> a -> Bool
   x /= y = not (x == y)
```

where we define `==` and `/=` in terms of each other. These defaults, however, will cause non termination (or out-of-memory) if both are used together, as it happens in the case where an instance does not provide any definition. Indeed, in such case using either will get the program stuck into an infinite (mutual) recursion.

To prevent this issue, GHC raises a warning if we don't define at least one of them, provided we enable warnings.

About your case: in class `Show` we also have two methods whose defaults are mutually recursive. Indeed, in the [docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Show) we read that we have to define at least one of them:

> Minimal complete definition
>
> ```
> showsPrec | show
> ```

Even in this case, GHC warns if we don't define at least one of those members, provided we enable warnings.

This is one of several Haskell pitfalls which can be prevented by enabling warnings. Because of this, I strongly recommend that you always keep warnings on, e.g. using the `-Wall` compiler flag.

Comment: ...and OP can get the behavior the want by replacing `instance Show T` (i.e. make an instance without overriding the defaults) with `deriving instance Show T` (i.e. use GHC's mechanism for writing a complete `Show` instance from scratch).